# Execute Spring Integration flows in parallel

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, amqp

If I have a simple IntegrationFlow like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow downloadFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("rabbitQueue1")
        .handle(longRunningMessageHandler)
        .channel("rabbitQueue2")
        .get();
}
```

... and if the `rabbitQueue1` is filled with messages,

what should I do to handle multiple messages at the same time? Is that possible? 
It seems that by default, the handler executes one message at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's true, by default endpoints are wired with `DirectChannel`. That's like performing a plain Java instructions one by one. So, to do some parallel job in Java you need an `Executor` to shift a call to the separate thread.

The same is possible with Spring Integration via an `ExecutiorChannel`. You  can make that `rabbitQueue1` as an `ExecutorChannel` bean or use this instead of that plain name:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.executor("rabbitQueue1", someExecturorBean)
```

and all the messages arriving to this channel are going to be paralleled in the threads provided by an executor. That `longRunningMessageHandler` are going to process your messages in parallel.

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#channel-implementations

Comment: What happens if I add a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor Bean to the context with queuecapac=50, corepoolsize=5, maxpoolsize=10?

Comment: The `ExecutorChannel` is nothing more than delegator to the provided `Executor`. Not sure what is your question in context...

Comment: Assuming you are using the message-driven channel adapter, you should not use an `ExecutorChannel` unless you are manually acknowledging messages. Otherwise you can lose in-process messages after a failure. Instead increase the `concurrency` in the inbound channel adapter to process multiple messages at the same time. You might also need to reduce the prefetch from the default (250) so the messages are distributed across the container threads.